# Polymer on Google App Engine - Java server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, polymer

I want to use Polymer with a Java server-side on Google AppEngine but in the Polymer documentation it says to modify the app.yaml file with url redirect like that:

```
handlers:
- url: /bower_components
  static_dir: build/bundled/bower_components
  secure: always

- url: /images
  static_dir: build/bundled/images
  secure: always

- url: /src
  static_dir: build/bundled/src
  secure: always

- url: /service-worker.js
  static_files: build/bundled/service-worker.js
  upload: build/bundled/service-worker.js
  secure: always

- url: /manifest.json
  static_files: build/bundled/manifest.json
  upload: build/bundled/manifest.json
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  static_files: build/bundled/index.html
  upload: build/bundled/index.html
  secure: always
```

My problem is: how can i do it without using the app.yaml?

In GAE i can't use app.yaml (in java 7 standard environment).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late but this might help someone:
I think you can achieve the same using the [<static-files>](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#static_files) directive. Instead of mapping in `app.yaml` you can map each individual folder/file like this. Then you just have to include the files properly in your `war` file.

EDIT:
As I am looking more into this probably a better way would be using [services/modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine) and a [dispatch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/dispatchref) file. You can look for inspiration in [this project](https://github.com/googlesamples/cloud-polymer-go) where they use Go/Polymer but it is the same problem.